# How to define a predicate meaning an object is a vector space from vector space axioms?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am trying to define a predicate that tells you something is a vector space from the 8 vector space axioms listed below:

VS1: $\forall u,v,w.(u+v)+w = u+(v+w)$ 
VS2: $\forall u.\exists \vec{0}.u+\vec{0}=\vec{0}+u=u$ 
VS3: $\forall u.\exists y.u+y=\vec{0}$ $\quad$ [$y$ can be denoted as $-u$ ] 
VS4: $\forall u,v. u+v = v+u$ 
VS5: $\forall \alpha, u, v. \alpha(u+v) = \alpha u + \alpha v$ $\quad$[$\alpha$ is a scalar] 
VS6: $\forall \alpha, \beta, v. (\alpha + \beta)v = \alpha v + \beta v$ $\quad $[$\alpha$, $\beta$ are scalars] 
VS7: $\forall \alpha, \beta, v. (\alpha\beta)v = \alpha(\beta v)$ $\quad$ [$\alpha$,$\beta$  are scalars] 
VS8: $\forall u, 1 \cdot u = u$ $\quad$ [$1$ is a scalar from the field that has some properties]

So, the predicate should be something like:

$$ \text{VectorSpace}(X) \Leftrightarrow \text{All 8 axioms hold for $X$.}$$

The problem is that the axioms are numbered and axiom 3 depends specifically on axiom 2. **You need a neutral element for addition before you can have an inverse element for addition, which is defined through a neutral element (the zero vector).** 
The obvious solution to my title question would be: $$\text{(A)} \quad\text{VectorSpace}(X) \Leftrightarrow VS1 \wedge VS2 \wedge VS3 \wedge ... \wedge VS8$$
Where VS(number) is an appropriate statement written above. But associativity and commutativity of conjunction make any statement with a mixed order of conjunction elements equivalent to statement (A), such as:

$$\text{(B)} \quad\text{VectorSpace}(X) \Leftrightarrow VS1 \wedge VS3 \wedge VS2 \wedge ... \wedge VS8$$

My question is, is my vector space predicate (A) the same as what the axioms require, and why? One idea I had was, that because all the elements of a chain of conjunctions must be correct at the same time for the compound statement to be correct, one can refer to a different statement in the chain irrespective of the order in which they appear, thus making both my definitions (A) and (B) correct, as well as any other that includes all 8 axioms regardless of ordering.

My second idea is, that (A) and (B) are both wrong, because you can't specify order within different elements of a conjunction, so that axiom 3 cannot "see" axiom 2's zero vector, and doesn't know what it is. If this is the case, how would one define such a predicate then? Does it even exist / is it definable?

Comment: Order of conjuncts doesn't affect truth of the predicate, though it may affect readability.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time. I think I understand that part, as (A) and (B) are always both true or both false. I was trying to display how you cannot actually have an order with conjuncts, but axioms do have an order, and it's unclear to me how to capture this concept (order and referencing back to a previous statement) with logical connectives.

Comment: Axioms 2 and 3 together characterize $0$, and neither presupposes the other.

Comment: Then I have completely misunderstood the concept of the zero vector. If that's the case, the axioms do not have an order (as the rest are independent as well), and the predicates (A) and (B) would both characterize them. Could you confirm this? Thank you for the comment, again.

Comment: I can confirm this.